# Checks input of 'fgets' in C

Tags: c, fgets

I want to check whether the user writes less than 30 characters or not. This is my code below but it can't check user's input by the way I would like. For example if I type 40 characters as input it won't print `Not valid input`. Could anyone explain me how to check that input will be right?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char string[31];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    if (fgets(string, 30, stdin)) {
        printf("Enter a character too: ");
        char c;
        scanf("%c", &c);

        char *ptr = string;

        if (ptr = contains(ptr, c)) {
            printf("Found at position %ld\n", ptr - string + 1);
        } else {
            printf("Character did not found.\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Not valid input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is because the `fgets()` is doing what you told it to do which is: read 30 bytes from `stdin`. The `fgets()` successfully read the 30 bytes out of those 40 bytes the user entered. That is why it is not going to the `else` statement you would like it to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets()` reads entire lines **and keeps the newline in the buffer**. If the buffer is smaller than needed, the buffer will not contain the newline, which, along with the rest of the line, will be read in a subsequent call to `fgets()`.

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
size_t len = strlen(buffer);
if (!len) /* mal-formed input */;
if (buffer[len - 1] != '\n') /* error if not eof */;
```

Comment: Not true.  If the buffer is too small, the entire line is not read.

Comment: That's what I mean @stark. Will try and improve answer, thanks.

Comment: @stark fixed EOF problem where len == 0

Answer (score -2):

You could try:

```
char string[32];
printf("Enter a string: ");
if(fgets(string,32,stdin)>30) {
   printf("Error: Too many characters");
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: [`fgets()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) returns a pointer.